# Identification of a young tree in the alpine region of southeastern France

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

I have a young tree growing in my backyard (in Grenoble, France), and I was not able to identify it, despite searching with many identifier tools.

It's 2 years old now and must be 2 meters high. It has a grey trunk, its leaves grow on brown/red stems that protrude irregularly from the trunk.

[image: Large view]

The leaves are pointed, gently serrated, covered with a light fuzz, with a distinct lattice of veins.

[image: View of the leaves]

Could you help me identify it?

Comment: This reminds me of "lilas" (Syringa): http://www2.csdm.qc.ca/st-fabien/projets/arborophile/Lilas/lilas.htm I'm not at all confident about the identification, though.

Comment: I have a lilas nearby, unfortunately they do not look alike. The lilas leaves are smooth and go two by two. Sorry for taking so much time to reply. The tree is still growing really fast, some of its leaves are huge, but there is still nothing more to help identification, no fruit or flower.

Comment: Could you add a photo with a zoom on the connection between a leaf and a branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree grew its first fruits this spring, so that I could definitely identify it: it is a goat willow! This is consistent with its spontaneous sprouting in my yard, as it is a common tree in my region.

[image]

[image]